# .htaccess redirect and rewrite url if REQUEST_URI starts with specific path

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I am working on a Wordpress site, it requires a plugin that needs to access the API endpoint of WP.

It wants to access the site's:

```
http://myhost.test/wp/wp-json/erp/v1/hrm/employees/1\?include\=department,designation,reporting_to,avatar,roles
```

but changes to the folder structure, causes the real, and actual link should be:

```
http://myhost.test/wp-json/erp/v1/hrm/employees/1\?include\=department,designation,reporting_to,avatar,roles
```

as you can see, there should be no `/wp` at the start of the `%{REQUEST_URI}`

I am trying to make this work: but it won't redirect the request:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp/wp\-json/
RewriteRule ^/wp/wp\-json(.*) /wp\-json$1 [L,R]
```

I do not understand what I am doing wrong,

I am catching everything after `^/wp/wp-json` then forward it to `^/wp-json`

What is going on?

Regards,

Comment: If you are using this inside a .htaccess file, remove the leading `/` from the `RewriteRule`'s first arg. I am not sure that is the only issue, but within .htaccess, mod_rewrite does not ever receive the leading `/` as it would in a `<Directory>` or `<VirtualHost>` context.  It would start matching as `^wp` rather than `^/wp` as in`RewriteRule ^wp/wp\-json(.*) /wp\-json$1 [L,R]`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yup, i think that's the answer, can you please create that solution so I can mark it as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using mod_rewrite in .htaccess context vs a `<Directory>` or `<VirtualHost>` context each have slightly different requirements in how the patterns are parsed. Most importantly to your situation, in .htaccess the first argument to `RewriteRule` is not matched against a leading slash `/` because the pattern is considered relative to the directory it is in.

Remove the leading `/` from your `RewriteRule` matcher argument:

```
RewriteRule ^wp/wp\-json(.*) /wp\-json$1 [L,R]
```